# showing result searching in another class

Tags: javascript

this code show results searching of list by javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

and html code is :

```
 <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

but i want js code searching of first li list and saved them , and finally show the results to another place (id= submenuItems) like this class:

```
<li>
    <div class="dropdownlink"><i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true"></i>tittle
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="submenuItems">
        <li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/txe1sp43/45/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names...">

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul> 

<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Albert</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Audrey</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Beau</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bonny</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Clyde</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christine</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chris</a></li>
</ul> 

<ul id="submenuItems"></ul>
```

And the Javascript:

```
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const out = document.getElementById("submenuItems");

// Define event-listener for keyup event
input.onkeyup = () => {
    // Clear outputlist
  out.innerHTML = "";

  // Don't do anything if input field has been cleared
  if (input.value === "") return;

  // Declare variables
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  const ul = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL");
  const res = [];

  // Loop through all lists and look for matches to filter
  for (let j = 0; j < ul.length; j++) {
    const li = ul[j].getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      const a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      // For each match, add a new li to output and insert a copy of the link to that
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        const newLi = out.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        newLi.appendChild(a.cloneNode(true));  
      }
    }    
  }

};
```

Comment: this code working but i've a few   <ul id="myUL">....</ul>    and your code only searching first list myUL

Comment: Well, ids should be unique to a page. Maybe you get what you want when you change the initialization of the input variable to sth. like document.getElementsByTagName("ul") and then go over that collection.

Comment: So if I change the <ul id = "myUL"> to <ul class= "myUL"> how can we write code that code working!?

Comment: Perhaps we could use document.getElementsByClassName("myUL") for the initialization and then iterate over the returned collection like we would with an array, doing the looping part for each element.

Comment: i've used and replaced document.getElementByClassName("myUL")  instead of document.getElementById("myUL") but it didn't work
are you can do that?

Comment: But when typed word for searching and press backspace and cleaned input value ,  show all li list!!!

Comment: all of li list target has # , each li list has unique href
but this code only directed to #

Comment: I was working off your code, which is set up thusly. I've altered the hrefs to take on the value of the source.

Comment: again not working , because tittle of li insert in href tag instead of each li link

Comment: I'd say it's working as intended. Where is the code to take the link destinations from? Your post doesn't include any hint as to that. If your actual code does contain real links, then you could store them along with the name and include them dynamically, as I've updated my answer to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('submenuItems').innerHTML = '';
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById('myUL');
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      var newA = document.createElement('a');
      newA.setAttribute('href', '#');
      
      newA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
         li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent));
      
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.appendChild(newA);            
      document.getElementById('submenuItems').appendChild(newLi);

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<p>
Found stuff
<ul id="submenuItems">
</ul>
</p>
```